# GetNamedSecurityInfo fails for registry key where GetSecurityInfo succeeds

Tags: c, winapi, acl, advapi32

I have a registry key ACL reading request like this:

```cpp
PACL dacl = NULL;
PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR secDesc = NULL;
if (GetNamedSecurityInfoW(L"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\SOFTWARE\\SomeSoftware\\SomeKey", SE_REGISTRY_KEY, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, NULL, NULL, &dacl, NULL, &secDesc) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
{ /*... */ }
```

And it fails with error 87, invalid parameter. However, if I use

```cpp
HKEY handle;
DWORD Ret = RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"SOFTWARE\\SomeSoftware\\SomeKey", 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &handle);
if (Ret != ERROR_SUCCESS) { /* ... */ }

DWORD secDescSize = 4096;
secDesc = LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED, secDescSize);
Ret = (DWORD)RegGetKeySecurity(handle, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, secDesc, &secDescSize);
if (Ret != ERROR_SUCCESS) { /* ... */ }
```

`RegOpenKey()` and `RegGetKeySecurity()` succeed, and running `GetSecurityDescriptorDacl()` on the result of `RegGetKeySecurity()` also works.

This code works fine for `SE_FILE_OBJECT` and reading a directory's ACL.
This code is inside a 32-bit DLL in a 32-bit app in Windows 10 Pro 64-bit. I'm targeting XP and above, using Visual Studio 2019 Preview.

Anything I could have missed in parameter validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`L"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\SOFTWARE\\SomeSoftware\\SomeKey"` is not a valid object name for `GetNamedSecurityInfoW()`. Read the [SE_OBJECT_TYPE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/accctrl/ne-accctrl-se_object_type) documentation for the proper format to use for a registry key:

> SE_REGISTRY_KEY
>
> Indicates a registry key. A registry key object can be in the local registry, such as **CLASSES_ROOT**\*SomePath* or in a remote registry, such as \\*ComputerName*\**CLASSES_ROOT**\*SomePath*.
>
> **The names of registry keys must use the following literal strings to identify the predefined registry keys: "CLASSES_ROOT", "CURRENT_USER", "MACHINE", and "USERS".**

Try `L"CURRENT_USER\\SOFTWARE\\SomeSoftware\\SomeKey"` instead.

Comment: Works great! *sigh*. So apparently obvious. Now to add code to ensure the inheriting devs don't make the same mistake. Thanks, though!